# RedisCacheManager TTL not Working

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot 2.0 with spring-data-redis and for some reason the entrTtl value of 200 seconds (Time to Live/cache expiry time)  is not being taken into account. Is there anything that I'm missing here?

REDIS CONFIG File below:

```
@Bean(name = "cacheManager")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration =
                RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                        .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(200))
                        .disableCachingNullValues();

        System.out.println("IN CACHE");
        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = RedisCacheManager.builder(jedisConnectionFactory()).cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration).build();
        return redisCacheManager;
    }
```

My method for retrieving the values that needs to be cached is annotated with the @Cacheable Annotation
@Cacheable("cachedprops")